# how to pass a primary key to a view in django?

Tags: django, primary-key, django-generic-views

I am trying to implement a class based view that should create a update form to update my model form but I don not know how to pass the pk from my base.html to my view:

viewvs.py:

```
from artdb.models import *

class UpdateForm(UpdateView):

    print('updateform')
    model=Date
    fields=['activity']
    template_name='updateForm.html'
```

updateForm.html:

```
{% extends "artdb/base.html" %}

{% block upd %}
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
     <input type="submit" value="Update">
     </form>
{% endblock upd %}
```

base.html:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-secondary"  href="{% url 'artdb:updateform' %}" role="button">update form &raquo;</a></p
{% block upd %}
{% endblock upd %}
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('<pk>/updateform/',views.UpdateForm.as_view(),name='updateform'),
]
```

I think that pk should be passed in the base.html but I am not shure how. Any suggestions?

Comment: not sure wich view you are referring to, there is only one view that I am using (shown above). Should I put the link in the updateForm.html instead?

Comment: In the update form view you don't need the link at all. You already have a submit button. You can use the URL tag to set the form's action, e.g. `<form action="{% url 'artdb:updateform' object.pk %}" method="post">`.

Comment: ok, I tried object.pk but then I got the "NoReverseMatch at /" error. This is a bit confusing

Comment: You have only shown one URL pattern for `/<pk>/updateform/`. You haven't shown the URL pattern or view for `/`.

Comment: ok, I think I misunderstood updateview. What I wanted to do is to create an object and then save it, i.e using createview instead. updateview just updates an existing object. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've probably got it by now, but if you didn't, try it like this in the app url.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('updateform/<int:pk>',views.UpdateForm.as_view(),name='updateform'),
]
```

Comment: yeah something like that. the key was elf.request.GET.get() function.